# App crashing since adding Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have been having issues since I added `Firebase` for analytics. I have spent several hours trying to find a solution but nothing has worked. The error I am getting is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcL(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzt; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzt' appears in /data/app/ist311njb.sustainability-WtBugfLSabsasKVrqCVeyw==/base.apk)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source:62)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:15)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:17)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6285)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` and `repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
}
```

in my root `build.gradle` and my app build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ist311njb.sustainability"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar'){
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you using version 11.0.4 for all Firebase and Google Play libraries?  Post your entire app module build.gradle file.

Comment: @BobSnyder I have updated the post with the entire app buid.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I found: put `force = true;` inside the following in gradle:

```
 compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1') {
        force = true;
    }
```

Comment: That worked for getting it working. What is the reason that this worked but using the latest version did not?

Comment: you can try with the latest version, and only add the force=true

Comment: I tried switching them back to the latest version but keeping the force=true but that caused the crash again

Comment: I have switched back to the version in your post and it still is getting the error now

Comment: :( try to clean the project.. if it worked once there is no reason it won't work now...

Comment: Yes thanks after cleaning the project I was able to use the latest version as well. I had tried cleaning a few other times I just never had found anything about trying the force = true